# Protractor and Jenkins integration

Tags: jenkins, protractor, selenium-chromedriver

I am pretty sure that this is an old problem and must have been solved by many of you.I am trying to run my current protractor-cucumber test cases via Jenkins.The tests wouldn't trigger when it comes down to opening chromedrive and fails. Since the protractor have inbuilt support for selenium-standalone server which updates/installs the chromedriver.I was expecting that I wouldn't have to provide the binary file for chromedriver explicitly. Please let me know if that's what I need to do to make this thing going.

Apparently team city works fine.I don't have to setup any path for binary anywhere.

Can you please advice on this problem.Thanks

Comment: What command you are using currently to kick start protractor in Jenkins? Also the exact error you are getting currently?

Comment: There should be more information on this question. What are you doing to download the binaries? how are you starting the selenium standalone server? What does your configuration look like?

Comment: @VishalAggarwal I have a custom js script that install the dependencies such as protractor, cucumber and protractor-cucumber-framework and then spawns a task ('node', 'protractor-path', 'path-to-e2e-test',baseUrl, specs). As for the error the error that stops the build is given below, I am not too worried about this error as it appears when the test wasn't able to navigate to the url and we try to clear the browser session storage.

Comment: `Error E/launcher - <unknown>: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Storage is disabled inside 'data:' URLs.`

Comment: @cnishina the drive binaries are downloaded by using `node webdriver-manager update`.I am not spinning up the selenium Server separately rather protractor has built-in support for the standalone server which starts the server instance on it's own and protractor config file looks https://jsfiddle.net/gaurvar/f7ugoxp4/

Comment: What version of Protractor are you on? Have you installed chrome? Did you install xvfb? Did this work ever or is this the first time setting up this job? What are your protractor log messages?

Comment: protractor version 4.0.11, yeah chrome is there, No i didn't install xvfb i am on a windows machine(does xvfb works for windows?). This is first time i am setting up this job. I am just getting the 'Error E/launcher - <unknown>: Failed to read the 'sessionStorage' property from 'Window': Storage is disabled inside 'data:' URLs.' which I believe appears when the test wasn't able to navigate to the url and we try to clear the browser session storage.

Comment: At first read, this question appears to be something about a typical Jenkins + Protractor set up. I think you should revise the question and add the error message and if you have any Protractor code that is doing something to manipulate `window.sessionStorage`. Also other questions that you should answer: is your selenium server started locally? You should include more logs / more information.

Answer (score -1):

Hi I encountered that error myself and I found 2 solutions:

1. In the machine that runs Jenknis have webdriver started all the time, that way when you run your tests Jenkins doesn't initialize webdriver.
2. Instead of running Jenknis as a service run it as an administrator, that way Jenkins will be able to run webdriver

Good Luck!

Comment: seems like not working - i started the webdriver before kicking off the build from jenkins but same result. Also jenkins service is running as me and I am the admin for my machine. Is there any other way to initialize the driver.How about providing the chrome binary path in jenkins as env variable??

Comment: Being administrator didn't work for me either. What command are you running? Can you show us your protractor config file? Where are you pointing your seleniumAddress?

Comment: protractor has builtin support for selenium standalone server. so I am not using the seleniumAddress config parameter in jenkins build protractor config file.because for running locally(without CI tool) we don't need selenium Address parameter. I will give it another try with seleniumAddress but is there any other way around? why jenkins couldn't initialize the driver?